# Rails 5 error when creating model instance with foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models in use at this point: Airports and Flights.
Flights belong to both an origin airport and destination airport. When I try to create a Flight model instance, I get the following error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.destination_airports

I have set up my code to match the example here: https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/active-record-associations

I've researched the problem (here and elsewhere), but can't turn up anything that seems to match my situation. I can't figure out what's going wrong. Has to be something simple. Something with the migrations, maybe? Thanks in advance for the help.

Relevant code:

Airport model:

```
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :departing_flights, foreign_key: "origin_airport_id", 
class_name: "Flight"
  has_many :arriving_flights, foreign_key: "destination_airport_id", 
class_name: "Flight"

  validates :abbreviation, presence: true, length: { is: 3 }

end
```

Flight model:

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin_airport, class_name: "Airport"
  belongs_to :destination_airport, class_name: "Airport"
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :passengers, through: :bookings
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateAirports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :airports do |t|
      t.string :abbreviation
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateFlights < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :flights do |t|
      t.references :origin_airport, foreign_key: true
      t.references :destination_airport, foreign_key: true
      t.datetime :depart_time
      t.datetime :arrive_time
      t.integer :capacity
      t.string :airline
      t.string :flight_number

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post answers as such and not as part of a question!

Comment: Thanks. This was my first post on here, so I wasn't sure of the proper way to do it. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the filenames of the migrations, perhaps they are not being run in the correct order?

Also, you may just need to run the migration in the right environment (`RAILS_ENV=development`)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Wasn't the problem, but worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found the (an?) answer - changing the migration for the flights table to replace t.references with t.integer and the column name with "x_id" corrects the problem. So, does references only work if using the model name for the column id?